# C# project not reporting any metric on SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

I am using - .NET framework 4.5.2, SonarQube 5.0, sonar runner 2.4, Analysis Bootstrapper for VS plugin 1.2, C# plugin 3.3.

When I run SonarQube analysis, I see my .sln file being found, files get recognized as CS, files get indexed, Analysis Successful message gets displayed on the console. But when I see the dashboard of the project on SonarQube server, I see no metrics getting reported. Even LOC, Duplications, Complexity widgets say 'No Data'.

Whereas, on the same setup, I am able to run few other C# projects successfully. I am unable to figure out, what is wrong with the config for this project.

Regards,
Anantha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible is that your project is being recognized as a test project, for which metrics and issues are not imported in SonarQube. By default, it tests for the presence of `test` or `Test` in your project name. Check the logs at the beginning of the analysis to see how the Visual Studio Bootstrapper Plugin detected your projects. You can change this behavior by setting the `sonar.visualstudio.testProjectPattern` property to a different (Java) regular expression.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh for the suggestion. Changing the regular expression for `sonar.visualstudio.testProjectPattern` solved the issue. Just a thought - could there be a better way for C# plugin to interpret test projects than the `*[Tt]est.*` regex?

Comment: Yep we're thinking about it for the MSBuild Runner (which is going to replace the Visual Studio Bootstrapper plugin)